# Write SQL Query for Getting Every Items within a Given List

Tags: mysql, sql

I was required to write a query, which should return only items that match every condition in other many-to-many tables association. 
It means that it is not sufficient that there is a child item from the provided list, but rather a child must exists for each and every item in the provided list. 
So, I went to something like this:

```
select distinct ti.id 
    from table1 ti 
    where `sizeOfField2IdList` = 
            (
            select count(*) 
            from table2 t2 
            where t1.fieldX1 = t2.fieldY1 and t2.field2 IN (`field2IdList`)
            );
```

Does anyone can suggest a better alternative for my needs? 
I hope this may assist anyone how need something similar.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

> must exists for each and every item in the provided list.

Yes there is an alternative solution, by group by this id and use `HAVING` the count of field 2 equal to `sizeOfField2IdList`:

```
SELECT ti.id
frp, table1 as ti
inner join table2 as t2 on  t1.fieldX1 = t2.fieldY1 
Where t2.field2 IN ($field2IdList)
group by ti.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.field2) = $sizeOfField2IdList
```

(Assuming that both `$field2IdList` and `$sizeOfField2IdList` will be provided as a predefined variables to the query.)